# Memory allocation during startup of a C++ program

Tags: memory, embedded, flash-memory

I sometimes read that the code segment is placed into ROM/FLASH. Others state that it is also loaded into RAM.
Is my understanding correct that it is common to place it into FLASH primary memory in case of an embedded system? And what are the advantages? I assume the startup of the program will be faster but since the FLASH memory is much slower it would be better to additionally load it from FLASH to RAM during the startup phase when RAM usage does not matter?

Comment: Where code segment is located on/loaded to depends on the hardware architecture.

Answer (score 2):

Sometimes you don't have enough memory for your program, so you just leave it in ROM or flash. On a system flush with memory you just load everything into RAM, it's much faster.

Some embedded CPUs have 2K of memory, but 2MB of flash. As an example the [RP2040](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/RP2040) has 264KB of SRAM (RAM) but 2MB of Flash memory for your programs. That's a lot bigger than the memory footprint.

Flash is slow compared to modern DRAM but in an embedded environment the CPU isn't always that fast either. The RP2040 only runs at 133MHz, so it won't notice the difference between flash latency and SRAM latency like a chip running in the 2GHz range might. It's clocked 15x slower.

If you want to explore this more, embedded CPUs like the RP2040 are really cheap, some less than $1, so you can experiment on them and see how it plays out in real life without having to spend much money at all.

Answer (score 2):

Generally, RAM is much faster than flash. Where to run the code from however, depends on the system. On most traditional embedded systems, you don't execute from RAM.

- On low-end embedded systems (8 and 16-bitters) you always keep all code in flash and there won't be a performance difference between executing from RAM or flash. Such systems typically don't have a MMU nor protection against writing to the code area, so running code from RAM is highly dangerous since bugs can write straight into physical memory. Also, these systems tend to have very limited RAM.
- On mid-range embedded systems (Cortex M etc) where you start to clock the core faster than the flash can keep up with, you need to introduce *wait states*, where the CPU waits for the flash to read. Typically you need wait states when you go beyond somewhere around 40-50MHz system clock on modern systems. The higher the clock, the more wait states you need.
  Such systems do not typically execute code from RAM either, since they usually don't need extreme performance. And they typically don't have a lot of RAM either. In some cases like mid-range Power PC, you'll have instruction cache, which helps a lot in compensating for the slower flash, since instructions can be pre-loaded from flash to cache by branch prediction.
- On high-end systems (Cortex A, x86 etc) there will be lots of RAM available for the purpose of executing the code from there and then you are expected to do so. On these systems, cache rather serves the purpose of speeding up access to RAM.

Historically, RAM was also much more prone to electromagnetic interference and could also lose charge over time unless you kept writing to the cells, so you didn't want to keep code in RAM for those reasons alone. That's not much of an issue today though.

Comment: If I am having a lot of RAM available is there any advantage to store the code in primary flash memory compared to secondary memory? For example is loading into RAM faster?

Comment: @Alex As evident from this answer, asking such a question without a specific system in mind doesn't make any sense.

Comment: Let's say I am having quite a high-end embedded Linux system which is comparable to a modern PC.

Comment: @Alex I doubt Linux can function at all unless you run it from RAM.